# How to convert oracle binary(OracleDbType.Raw) to guid

Tags: c#, oracle, type-conversion

My code is read as follows:

```
OracleCommand cmd = CreateCommand(query, connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parameter, OracleDbType.Raw, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));

OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var v = cmd.Parameters[parameter].Value
value =new Guid(v as byte[]);
if (result == 1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't work properly.
Problem I think is that casting to `byte[]` is not working properly.

Can anyone help me out?

I made it work with help from T.S and corrected my code as below:

```
  var op = new OracleParameter(parameter, OracleDbType.Raw,32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            op.Size = 32;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(op);
```

Thanks to T.S

Comment: Can you place mouse over `v` and tell me, what Type that is?

Comment: It say binary. that's all.

Comment: it says oraclebinary. corrected

Comment: How was the GUID generated? _GUIDs (in C#) have some 'interesting' behaviours in terms of converting them to bytes - so the solution of how to deserialise them depends partly on how you serialised them._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `cmd.Parameters[parameter].Value` returns `OracleBinary`, do this

```
OracleBinary v = cmd.Parameters[parameter].Value
value = new Guid(v.Value);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleBinaryStructure.htm#ODPNT4417

Comment: length of array I got is 1(byte[1]) but it needs 16(byte[16])

Comment: @JoonwK Do set size of your parameter

Comment: how to set size of it?

Comment: @JoonwK where you have `new OracleParameter(parameter, OracleDbType.Raw, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)`. Its either another constructor overload or declare `OracleParameter p = new . . ` and then do `p.size = 36`, and then add to parameter collection.

Comment: @JoonwK do this: `new OracleParameter(parameter, OracleDbType.Raw, 36, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011683

Comment: @JoonwK Great. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
byte[] byte = cmd.Parameters[parameter].Value;
value = new Guid(v);
```

GUID takes a byte as constructor:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?
redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Guid__ctor_System_Byte___](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Guid__ctor_System_Byte___)